# Gradle: Do not execute quarkusBuild task when trigger sonarlint task

Tags: gradle, quarkus, sonarlint

I have the "io.quarkus" and the "name.remal.sonarlint" plugin in my build.gradle.
When I execute the "sonarlintMain" task then the quarkusBuild task is automatically
executed (I think because the build task is a dependency of sonarlint). Is it possible
to exclude the quarkusBuild (via command line or within the definition of the
sonarlint { ... } task) ?
I tried to exclude the task via command line with "-x quarkusBuild" but it did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, a few minutes later I found a solution:

```
    sonarlint {

    if (gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames().toString().contains("sonarlintMain")) {
        project.gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames.add('quarkusBuild')
        project.gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames.add('quarkusGenerateCode')
        project.gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames.add('quarkusGenerateCodeTests')
    }
```

Comment: This will only work, if `sonarlintMain` is called directly from the command line. If a task that depends on `sonarlintMain` is run, `quarkusBuild` will still run, too.

Comment: Thank you. That is true but was not relevant for me.